# Не могу загрузить json файл в БД django, который был выгружен из той же БД

Tags: python, django

Выгружаю модель в файлt json в django ,открываю его и получается что русские символы исказилась:

```
[
    {
      "model": "getlink_app.page",
      "pk": 1,
      "fields": {
        "name": "┴хы√щ ршёЄ",
        "content": "╩ЁрЄъюх юяшёрэшх: сюыюЄэр  яЄшЎр ёхьхщёЄтр ршёЄют√ї. ╬ёэютэ√х яЁшьхЄ√ Ц схыюх юяхЁхэшх ё ўхЁэ√ь эр ъЁ√ы№ ї, фышээ√щ Єюэъшщ ъЁрёэ√щ ъы■т ш фышээ√х ",
        "slug": "aist",
        "created": "2021-10-05T10:22:35.149Z",
        "updated": "2021-10-05T10:22:35.149Z"
      }
```

Потом пытаюсь этот выгруженный файл снова загрузить и выдает исключение UnicodeDecodeError, не могу понять как исправить, видимо при выгрузке искажается

Comment: Чем именно открываете? Какой-то консольный редактор?

Comment: в самом django открываю, а там уже искаженные символы.

Comment: "в самом django" - в админке или в консоли? Этот текст - в кодировке cp1251 отображенный в консольной кодировке cp866.

Comment: в PyCharm , когда выгружаю данные модели в чам проект, там создается файл.json , вот его в редакторе и открываю

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял, должно помочь. Выгружайте данные с параметром `-Xutf8`.

```
python -Xutf8 manage.py dumpdata > <ваше_название>.json
```

Comment: не помогло,все тоже самое ток все теперь в одну строчку записывает в создавшем файле .json